Agregar una key a cada elemento de una sublista en python
Tengo una lista de listas en python
lista = ['["MD","RS","FW"]','["AB","TR","WE"]']

Tengo una lista con las Key
Keys = ["Elemento1","Elemento2","Elemento3"]

Necesito un diccionario de la forma:
dict = {
    {
        "Elemento1":"MD", 
        "Elemento2":"RS",
        "Elemento3":"FW"
    },
    {
        "Elemento1":"AB",
        "Elemento2":"TR",
        "Elemento3":"WE"
    }
}


Eso no es un diccionario. No es código Python válido. Faltan las llaves.

Creo que lo que quieres como resultado final es una lista de diccionarios, que es justo lo que la respuesta de @ivancabrera proporciona

Para convertir tu lista de listas en una lista de diccionarios, puedes usar un bucle for en combinación con la función zip()
import json

lista = ['["MD","RS","FW"]','["AB","TR","WE"]']
keys = ["Elemento1","Elemento2","Elemento3"]

# Convertir las cadenas de la lista a listas
lista = [json.loads(i) for i in lista]

# Crear un diccionario para cada sublista
dict_list = [dict(zip(keys, sublist)) for sublist in lista]

print(dict_list)

Este código primero convierte las cadenas de la lista en listas usando la función json.loads(). Luego, para cada sublista en lista, crea un diccionario donde las claves son los elementos de keys y los valores son los elementos de la sublista. El resultado es una lista de diccionarios.
